# ARIMA model with delay in fitting and constant prediction

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, prediction, statsmodels

I am trying to use ARIMA (Python, `statsmodel`) on the following time series, values are collected with a weekly frequency:

```
2018-01-05    2.253999
2018-01-12    1.943268
2018-01-19    2.186222
2018-01-26    2.096893
2018-02-02    2.078723
2018-02-09    1.916794
2018-02-16    1.895745
2018-02-23    2.126000
2018-03-02    2.280271
2018-03-09    2.013397
```

I have no experience on ARIMA and just following generic suggestions on how to find p,q and d.
I can see the TS has a decreasing trend:

[image: Decomposition]

and differentiating with lag 1 (`train.diff()`) makes it stationary, hence `d=1`.
The ACF and PACF plots (of the differentiated TS), show negative autocorrelation at lag 1 and together with the partial autocorrelation dropping after lag 1, I'd chose `q=1` (MA = 1).

[image]
So, `ARIMA(p=0, d=1, q=1)`

```
model = ARIMA(train, order=(0, 1, 1))
model_fit = model.fit()
```

The model summary:

```
                          ARIMA Model Results                              
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                    D.y   No. Observations:                  103
Model:                 ARIMA(0, 1, 1)   Log Likelihood                  94.598
Method:                       css-mle   S.D. of innovations              0.096
Date:                Fri, 09 Oct 2020   AIC                           -183.195
Time:                        14:12:25   BIC                           -175.291
Sample:                    01-12-2018   HQIC                          -179.994
                         - 12-27-2019                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         -0.0021      0.004     -0.492      0.623      -0.010       0.006
ma.L1.D.y     -0.5635      0.115     -4.916      0.000      -0.788      -0.339
                                    Roots                                    
=============================================================================
                  Real          Imaginary           Modulus         Frequency
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
MA.1            1.7748           +0.0000j            1.7748            0.0000
```

Hints a good fit (p-value of MA < 0.05). Plus, there are no patterns in the residuals, and they are centered around 0

[image]
[image]

However, the model fit doesn't look great (`model_fit.plot_predict(dynamic=False)`). It suggests a delay in fitting the values to the TS.
[image]
Furthermore, when forecasting the next values (`model_fit.forecast(9)`)
[image]

I obtain an almost constant prediction value. I also tried adding `p=1` but results did not improve.
Is the TS having random patterns, hence impossible to predict? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach appears to be correct, and the predicted values in the ARIMA(0,1,1) case are consistent with the theory, such that the forecast of the MA(q) process converges to the process mean after q+1 lags. Adding an AR part may not make sense, looking at the autocorrelation plot, hence it is not suprising that an ARIMA(1,1,1) is not improving fit. The "delay" you are observing is also completely characteristic, its not like the model is predicting the future shock but rather weighting (read "dampening") the past shocks ultimately in the direction of the process mean. If you deal with a a true MA(1) process with small coefficient, the incoming noise is dominating the process behaviour so that there is not much forecasting you can do.

As a sidenote, p-values do not indicate good fit, more the fact that intuitively the coefficient indeed has the sign indicated by the estimation.